# php comparing POST['integer string'] with an integer from database

Tags: php, types, comparison

I have an integer coming from the form POST. I know that all POST variables are strings.

Suppose I want to compare this POST['integer string'] with an integer from the database as:
my_page_action.php =>

```
$query = "SELECT amount FROM table where id=:id";
$stmt = $conn_p->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$data = $stmt->fetch();

if ( ! empty($data)) {

    if ($data['amount'] != $_POST['amount']) {
        header("location:my_page.php?msg=Invalid Amount");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header("location:my_page.php?msg=Invalid Record");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Also can anyone suggest me the best way of handling validation error messages. I mean form submitting to another page and if errors exist redirect to same page or any other better way ?

Comment: Are you saing this is not working? What is you question?

Comment: No, i am asking for the right way for a comparison like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely the types of the variables are different, in this case I'm using float, but you could use intval, stringval, etc:

```
if (floatval($data['amount']) != floatval($_POST['amount'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intval($_POST['amount']` instead of just `$_POST['amount']`, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

You also have the float equivalent, floatval (http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Comment: but intval gives different result like: intval(0102) gives 66

Comment: @KuldeepThakur intval is not supposed to take anything else than string I guess, furthermore, I don't see much interest into using intval on an int.